# How to get geolocation by ip in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, ip

Anyone know if exist any API to obtain the estimated geolocation (latitude, longitude) of an android device using public IP?

Now I am able to get the IP address with the following method:

```
private void getIPAddress(){
    URL url;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
    InputStreamReader in=null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        in = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
              buffer.append(line);
              buffer.append('\r');
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        in.close();
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
        ip = json_data.getString("ip");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
         try {
            bufferedReader.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        if(urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect(); 
          }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use, a webservice to request your ip location. [This](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) API returns the location of an IP address (country, region, city, zipcode, latitude, longitude) and the associated timezone in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link (http://freegeoip.net/json/) to get all of the following information. The ip provided is the External ip address you are connected to.

JSON format: (but you can choose your format)

```
{
  "ip": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "XX",
  "region_name": "XXX XXXX",
  "city": "XXX XXXX",
  "zip_code": "10XXX",
  "time_zone": "America/New_York",
  "latitude": 4X.XXXX,
  "longitude": -7X.XXXX,
  "metro_code": 501
}
```